# More detailed explanation of arrays and mappings memory layout

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

[The docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) give a nice introduction to the memory layout in an EVM, but I'm still left with a question concerning mappings and arrays:

If the array itself is stored at slot i, its values start at keccak256(i). In case of uint256, every element of the array thus has as address keccak256(i) + index.
However, what prevents two different `i` values from having colliding addresses? Even in the case that the keccak256(x)never returns the same result for a different x, it could be that an array starts somewhere (address y), grows bigger (e.g. stores 10000 values), but that another array that mapped by keccak256 starts at `y + 512`, thus overlapping with the previous array. Is this logic correct? If so, how does the compiler prevent such collisions?

The same question can be applied to mappings

Answer (score 0):

> *what prevents two different i values from having colliding addresses*

Your logic is theoretically correct, but not applicable in practice.

The difference between `keccak(i)` and `keccak(i+1)` is so large, that much more than 10 thousand values can fit in between.

If you're very lucky to find a very close hash results, the difference might be around 10^20 (that's a "one and twenty zeros"). So in combination with having to pay transaction fees to push each item of the array - not possible in practice.

> *how does the compiler prevent such collisions?*

The Solidity compiler has nothing to do with preventing hash collisions. Its task is "only" to translate the Solidity code into the EVM compatible bytecode.

Comment: Thanks!
I know that the difference in values between `keccak(i)` and `keccak(i+1)` is _supposed to_ be large. However, hash functions do not guarantee this 100% (unless keccak is special?). So theoretically it could be possible that there are 2 values `x` and `x+1` which map to the same value, or very close to it.

And you're right, I meant how does the *EVM* prevent such a collision from happening, or does it assume, since the odds are so low, that it never happens?

Comment: @Jasper The EVM does not prevent such collision from happening on technical level. I don't have that deep knowledge of cryptography but from my understanding keccak does not solve this in any other way than other hashing functions... However the need to pay gas fees for every write operation mitigates the risk that someone would resize the array to such large size that would cause the collision this way.